# Should I draw a button using a single shape (triangle list) and draw call, or multiple shapes and draw calls (triangle strip and line lists)?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es2

I know this is too simple for performance improvements to make much of a difference, but I find that knowing this information would be simple for many future scenarios. Basically, what I am trying to draw is a rectangle with text over it. I don't know whether it would be better to draw the entire thing using triangles, or use two draw calls (one using GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP for the rectangle, and the other using GL_LINES for the text). My worry is that the cost of the draw call outweighs the cost of reducing the number of vertices used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No two GPUs render `GL_LINES` the same way. You can be missing pixels at some of the corners on one GPU/driver, missing different pixels on another GPU/driver. Have it rendered thicker or thinner on different GPU/drivers. And more potential problems.

The look of the lines will also dramatically change according to the rendering resolution and anti-aliasing settings.

So you shouldn't use `GL_LINES` unless it's for displaying debugging information only during development. Never for a released product.

Here's an example of the inconsistencies with `GL_LINES`. Used here as a way to display the bounding boxes and mouse click events for **debugging** purposes during development.

[image]

Top is without anti-aliasing. Bottom is with MSAA 16x enabled.

---

The current methods commonly used to display text are:

- Put the text glyphs (characters) and possibly the background inside of 1 large texture called a texture atlas and render the text box in one `GL_TRIANGLES` draw call.
- "Bake" the text window with either the CPU or GPU into a texture and display that texture as a quad.

The first method saves on texture memory bandwidth and has better performance.

The second method is usually used when you want to do complex animated fades in and out of your entire text box in fancy ways (eg: make it look like it catches on fire and burns away).